# Why do I get Access Denied error when changing my password?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

My company just purchased a new dedicated server from a hosting company, and the guy who handled the acquisition gave me an account and a temporary password. When I remote desktop to the server, it asks me to change my password... when I change it, and hit enter, it just says "Access Denied" and doesn't change the password.

What is causing this? How can we fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to check (or get someone to check) the account is not set to not allow password changes.

For local accounts under computer management, it is one of the user account settings.

Answer (score 2):

As you have no access to the server without changing the password, you'll need to have the hosting company log into the server and correct any issues with it.